# Trying to make 1000 random folders using Python - os.makedirs()

Tags: python, operating-system

So I'm pretty new to python, learning a new concept a day. I'm testing out the OS module and I want to be able to make 1000+ random folders by without repeats. Below is my code, however the flaw is random.sample is giving me repeating numbers for some reason.

Also feel free to clean up the code and accomplish it in an easier way, I'm very new so would love to see new things.

```
import os
import random

#directory i want to make the folders in
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\miner2\\Desktop\\OS-Demo-2')

def newfl(foldername):
""" function that takes whatever you want to name the folder
and then adds a random number to the end of its name """

convert = random.sample(range(1,100000), 1)
return str(foldername) + ''.join((str(convert)))

#testing the function with print
print(newfl(1))

#attempting to make 10,000 folders by looping, but gives less because we get repeated folder names
i = 0
while i < 10000:
    os.makedirs('C:\\Users\\miner2\\Desktop\\OS-Demo-2' + '\\' + str(newfl('putfoldernamehere')))

    i += 1
```

Comment: update: this does it but i feel like it's very dirty

convert = random.sample(range(1,200), 15)
    return str(foldername) + ''.join((str(convert)))

Comment: You seem to already know how to take random samples - why not sample 10000 different values once instead of sampling 1 independent value 10000 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`random.sample()` samples without replacement, but that uniqueness is not preserved between function calls.

Also, `pathlib` is a nice alternative to the `os` module.

This should work:

```py
import pathlib
import random

base_path = pathlib.Path("C:/Users/miner2/Desktop/OS-Demo-2")

for i in random.sample(range(10000), k=500)):
    base_path.joinpath(f"folder_{i}").mkdir()
```